# Make sidebar floatable in Joomla

Tags: joomla1.5, sidebar

I have a website powered by Joomla 1.5.26 using template Ja Purity II
Demo template here

```
http://templates.joomlart.com/ja_purity_ii/
```

How can i make my right sidebar floatable ? I try to change it css position to absolute but it didnot work. Any one can help me !

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the class  column sidebar from index.php in templates files and can create you own class for right side bar.

```
 <div style="width:20%" class="column sidebar" id="ja-right">        
   To         
 <div style="width:20%" class="column-your-css sidebar-your-css" id="ja-right-your-css">
```